# php/mysql table with users settings

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I created this application, that displays widgets. Each widget is a `*.php` file that displays different type of data from the mysql database. Also I created a file `options.php`, that each user can access and they can change the `position` where each widget is displayed, the `height`, the `color`, and the `width`. (lets say the widget is a div with info pulled out for the database)

The issue I am having is how to store the data to be specific to the user. At this point after the button save is pushed it `UPDATES` all the rows while each row contains a specific widget options.

`For example:`
Options table has these fields: `[id] [name] [height] [position] [color]`. For now all users see the same placement because it is not user specific. I was thinking about storing all the widget names in 1 row with a separator, then all positions with a separator ...but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to store every field in a different column, is more clear and elegant, use separator in a column to store different values seems a bit nasty.

You can create a table widget configuration where you have different columns for the required parameters :)

Comment: thats what I did initially but they need to be user specific. there are 18 "widgets" each one has 5 parameters

Comment: Your table can have a id of user and widget.(or fk if you tables)

Comment: i.e.: Create a table which attributes are: (width, height, etc.., USER and WIDGET)

Answer (score 0):

If every widget has a different amount of settings ( therefore different amount of columns ) you could make one field blob and pass serialized array there. Other option is to find common fields for every widget and serialize only what is left in separate column.

To make widget settings

> specific to the user

just link corrent widget settings row to the user id. Better in same if every user will have personal row with settings.

All of the following is of course if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: all fields are common : height, width, position and color

Comment: @fogsy so all widgets have same fields. Well, then you can make classifier for widgets names and their ids. Other table will have customers for example. And third table can have all those fields ( height, width, position and color ) as separate columns, plus one column for widget id and one column for customer id. Also I think it would be correct to make complex unique key from customer id and widget id. I hope, that you where asking about that.

Answer (score 0):

You want one table for position options:

---

**Divtable:**
id - INT (You want this to be Auto Incrementing Primary Key)
Name - VARCHAR
userid - INT
Top - INT
Left - INT
Width - INT
Height - INT

---

the ID is the primary key, and really should be the first thing 
in damn near every MySQL Table...

---

The name is the name of the Div.

---

UserId is a *foreign key* in your table that **points** to the ID number on the "Users" table. 
Then you know which user owns that DIV, you can select all of HIS divs to redraw later easily, etc, etc...

---

you can get the user id number from the Users table by username (or whatever)...

```
select ID from `Users` where username='johndoe121'
```

Lets say it returns 21. Find all of /his/ DIV options now like so:

```
select * from `options` where userid = '21'
```